# How can I pass to JSON a DataFrame with overlapping names between the index and columns

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I need to convert to JSON format DataFrames similar to this:

```
                col1 col2  col3
col1 col2 col3                 
1    a    10       1    a    10
2    b    11       2    b    11
3    c    12       3    c    12
```

However, when I run `df.to_json(orient='table')` I'm getting the exception `ValueError: Overlapping names between the index and columns`. I understand why this happens, but I really would like to know if there is an easy way to circumvent the error. All I need is to convert the DataFrame to JSON maintaining the same indexes, and when restoring it, get the original DataFrame.

Here I leave a code snippet so you can reproduce the scenario.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'col3': [10, 11, 12]})
df = df.set_index(keys=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], drop=False)
df.to_json(orient='table')
```

Comment: What's the expected output? Your  dataframe doesn't make sense to me as it is, what does it mean to have all the columns in the index? Why have both? Are there other columns you're not showing that don't go in the index? If so, why not use `drop=True` in `set_index`?

Comment: I've no idea either, it's the algorithm I received and need to make it work for our workflow. Whatsoever, the sense of the dataframe isn't relevant. What I want as output is the same dataframe but as a CSV or JSON.